# Correct use of webhooks to assure payment integrity

Tags: php, transactions, stripe-payments, webhooks, payment

I'm new to webhooks and am not really getting the hang of some points of it. KISS; the current problem is, think about:

- a platform
- that provides a service X
- to book a service X, customer Y has to pay in advance
- every payment is authorized first only
- every payment is captured after the service has been received

From the booking of a service to the capture of the related payment, only the authorization is handled involving the client-side. All the rest is handled on the server-side.

For every possible case of a booking of a service on my platform, payment authorizations is requested as the first action on the server-side. Adaptations of the DB of the platform are only executed after a successful authorization of the payment from the frontend.

The only fallback webhook I implement is for the case where a customer books a service, authenticates, and then loses connection. Because in this case, the customer would have booked the service, but the platform server could not make the related updates. So the customer will have paid, but not receive his / her service via the platform.

My strategy is thus to implement a webhook to listen for the event of a transaction authorization "completed", and, if no transaction data is found internally, execute what needs to be done.

BUT, two questions popped up:

A) How can I control that a webhook gets executed AFTER the regular server-side script should have been executed? Delay the execution of the webhook script? What are the best pracs here?

B) If A) is possible, isn't it smarter to just cancel the authorized payment in the webhook, instead of coding the completion of every possible transaction via webhook? Already the thing that you lose the entire payload in case of a client who lost connection (the payload that you need to execute the server-side tasks after a payment authorization), and the consequent need of passing the according payload back-and-fourth to your payment API, while ensuring that CID is encrypted etc.; this just sounds like overkill to me.. Was anyone in the same situation, and also decided to just immediately cancel the just-authorized payment in lost connections via webhooks? Or must webhooks generally execute the exact same server-side script that the related server-validation would do? Meaning I have to find a way to pass the payload to my webhook function?

Comment: Ask Stripe support for help with this design. Seriously, they are really good at helping people like us do this kind of thing perfectly.Otherwise their support costs could crush them, not to mention us online sellers.

Comment: I mean in the end it all comes down to the question if a webhook script must execute the same stuff as your not-webhook script that gets triggered by a client request. And if so, how you can avoid that they interfere with each other, both executing the exact same script and thus the same DB transaction. This is rather not-stripe related, imho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The webhook is your notification that the event has happened - you're under no obligation to perform any processing right that moment, or ever.

If you're using webhooks as a backup to a primary synchronous flow (a good design!), then you can record the event and enqueue for later.

Stick a record somewhere indicating "got this authorization. Check this again in an hour to make sure the customer did the thing."

And to your comment above: you probably *don't* want your sync and async flows to be the same. Your async backup might involve contacting the customer eg via email, while that's not necessary for the sync flow since the customer is still on session.

Comment: Hmm I see, that's also a good approach! The only thing I'm afraid of in that case is the time elapsed in between the confirmation of the payment and the internal processing of the reservation (if sync failed)

Comment: But then additionally, that means that there's no way around a transaction race condition for that design, you agree?